# How to set up script or document to launch from top or side bar?

Tags: unity, 12.10, launcher, panel, shortcuts

I have searched for information about this, but not found anything directly related to it.

Is there a way to add a document (for example, a Libre Office file or text file) to open when clicked from the top bar or the side bar?  Similarly, is there a way to permanently  attach an icon to either the top or side bar that when clicked will launch a shell script or a perl script?  Dragging a text file, libre office file, or perl script to the launcher does not seem to work as it does for other applications.

Any ideas or suggestions on where to look for information about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is create a custom launcher for your scripts/documents.  You can do that in a text editor with the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name = NAME_TO_DISPLAY
Exec = COMMAND_TO_RUN
Icon = NAME_OR_PATH
```

Just save it with a `.desktop` extension and make it executable. If you save it in `~/.local/share/applications` the launcher will be accesible via the Dash.  Dragging it to the launcher bar will fix it there. The exec line to open a document or weblink should just be `xdg-open FILE` to open with a default program.  For more on the launcher file specifications see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

As a drag-n-drop shortcut to add files to launchers for quick execution via quicklists or mini-dashes, check out [Drawers](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/drawers) in the Software Center for purchase, or you can install it via [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ian-berke/+archive/ppa-drawers) for free (there will just be a reminder every 100 uses to donate, unless you donate).

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I ended up installing gnome-panel, per the instructions that you referenced [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles):  
    `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel` 
and then used it as follows:  
    `gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications appname.desktop`